# How to jitter only one categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I retain one variable (a single point) to not be jittered while keeping the jitter on the other categorical variable in ggplot?

Here is the code I am currently using and what the output looks like:

```html
# load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

# A basic scatterplot with color depending on Species
p <- ggplot(dt, aes(x=Type, y=y, color=Type)) + 
      geom_jitter(shape=22,
        alpha=0.5,
        size=2) +
     geom_hline(yintercept=c(1.4, 28.7, 2.65, 14.9)) +
     labs(y = 'ng/g lipid', title = 'PCB 99')
 
# Log base 10 scale
p + scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TyGN.png)

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to split your data in categories (or (single) observations) which you want to be displayed jittered and not to be jittered. The first set of data could then be passed to `geom_jitter` while for the second you could use `geom_point`.

Using `iris` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_jitter(
    data = iris[!iris$Species == "setosa", ],
    shape = 22,
    alpha = 0.5,
    size = 2
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = iris[iris$Species == "setosa", ],
    alpha = 0.5,
    size = 2
  )
```

[image]

Comment: it's twitching in my fingers to create a geom with jitter as an aesthetic :D (just for practice purpose of course)